# HOW to merge and get the difference between 2 datatable

Tags: datatable

we've created a function that merge 2 datatable.

here's the code

```
    Public Shared Function CompareTwoDataTable(ByVal dt1 As DataTable, ByVal dt2 As DataTable) As DataTable
    dt1.Merge(dt2)
    Dim d3 As DataTable = dt2.GetChanges()
    Return d3
End Function
```

i was wondering if the code was incorrect or what, my point is i want to determine the difference between those 2 table and get their difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who view this, this is the code i've come up to

i've created a function that compares the 2 datatable using their ids

`Public Shared Function CompareTwoDataTable(ByVal dt1 As DataTable, ByVal dt2 As DataTable) As DataTable
        Dim rows_to_remove As New List(Of DataRow)()
        For Each row1 As DataRow In dt1.Rows
            For Each row2 As DataRow In dt2.Rows
                If row1("ID").ToString() = row2("ID").ToString()  Then
                    rows_to_remove.Add(row1)
                End If
            Next
 Next
        For Each row As DataRow In rows_to_remove
            dt1.Rows.Remove(row)
            dt1.AcceptChanges()
        Next
        Dim d3 As DataTable = dt1
        Return d3
    End Function`

Hope it helps